# Prevent text from updating until component (Dialog, Snackbar, etc.) has closed

Tags: reactjs

I've implemented a [`Dialog`](https://mui.com/api/dialog/) component which displays the values of some state variables.

When the `Dialog` closes, the state variables are reset to default. The problem is that although the `Dialog` closes in less than a second, it's still enough time to see that the text has changed.

Is there a way to stop the text from changing until the `Dialog` has actually closed? I tried setting the `dialogOpen` state variable to `false` first, before resetting the other state variables to default, but it didn't help since it happens too fast and React [asynchronously batches](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) the state changes anyway.

```
<Dialog
    open = {dialogOpen}
    onClose = {() => handleDialogClose()}
    ... />
```

`handleDialogClose()`:

```
const handleDialogClose = () =>
{
    setDialogOpen(false)
    setStateVariables(DEFAULT_VALUES)
}
```

I think this issue is general to more components than just the `Dialog`, since it also happens with text that appears on [`Snackbar`](https://mui.com/components/snackbars/) components. A general solution to all of it would be best, but anything will help.

Edit: The `Dialog` uses a [`Fade`](https://mui.com/api/fade/) transition, where the `timeout.exit` delay is about 200ms. Using `setTimeout()` to delay updating the state variables works, per @technophyle's answer below. The delay passed to `setTimeout()` can be 0 and the extra time is still enough to prevent the change being seen.

Comment: Why do you need to reset `setStateVariables(DEFAULT_VALUES)`? Could you just have 1 state that holds the content of the Dialog? and any time you open the dialogue you update that state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky issue to resolve gracefully if your `Dialog` component has a CSS transition animation.

One solution (though not pretty) if you know the transition duration:

```
const handleDialogClose = () =>
{
    setDialogOpen(false)
    setTimeout(() => {
        setStateVariables(DEFAULT_VALUES)
    }, TRANSITION_DURATION_MS)
}
```

Comment: You're right, the `Dialog` uses a `Fade` transition. This solution works, and actually, the transition delay second parameter can be 0. It seems like extra the time just from calling `setTimeout` is enough